Why does cv::solveLP() impose the constraint x>=0 and what to do if your solution space can be negative?
I have a delaunay triangulation.
Each point has an absolute coordinate in R2. Each edge has a known x, y distance between each point. There is error, and so the solution of absolute coordinates cannot satisfy the system, it's over-determined.
I would like to find the solution of absolute coordinates that minimizes the inf norm of this system.
I have been using openCV HEAVILY for this project and so I intended to use cv::solveLP(). However, the answer cv::solveLP produced was way off.
After looking at the documentation, I saw that solveLP() imposes the constraint x >= 0. It seems this is not an option you can change. I realize that many real world LP problems revolve around numbers of objects, and often x >= 0 makes sense. But why would they impose this constraint without giving you the option?
Is there a way to still use this function for a solution where x can take on negative values?

Recommendation: Lead the Question with the question and fill in the gaps with the explanation after establishing what you are asking about. Focus the question on is there a way to still use this function for a solution where x can take on negative values?. why would they impose this constraint without giving you the option? is interesting for curiosity, but probably doesn't get you further ahead in the software problem you face.

it's implementation of Dantzig's simplex algorithm in canonical form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

[mre] required. I would also recommend using line/paragraph breaks to improve readability. [ask]

Feels like a harsh close by people not too familiar with mathematical-optimization: it's imho a valid abstract question linked to programming-APIs where no example is needed. Anyway... The x>=0 is what makes linear-programming powerful in general. For your question / case: search for the term "free variables". The general idea is to split these variables into a positive and negative part (2 variables!). Remark: if you are talking about opencv's implementation, keep in mind, that this is a toy-implementation (compared with Soplex, Highs, Clp, maybe GLPL, lp_solve and commercials)!

@sascha My main quirk with this is that OP didn't bother to use paragraphs or any other sort of mark-up to make the question at least a bit legible. And I still have trouble figuring out what the actual question is.

I see two aspects to OP's question: (1) the application is a delaunay triangulation but the given data overdetermines it, so OP wants to solve that with some "fuzziness" (2) OP asks about a property of the solver in OpenCV that is likely a general property of many other solvers. (2) seems to have well known solutions, or have been discussed extensively in literature.

if the question is merely "linked" to an API, but doesn't need it (no code), then this isn't a programming question, and should be addressed to a stack exchange for math/optimization/LPs -- (2): indeed I have little knowledge of LPs. it strikes me that such a constraint isn't actually a problem because maybe one can introduce compensating summands to shift this constraint downward or remove it (as you suggest) -- (1): the description is barely enough to get an idea, but the details are missing to possibly modify the problem without having to deal with the solver's "offending property".

do you want to post an answer? if you do, I might support reopening. feel free to include remarks on OpenCV's solver's deficiencies. that's useful to know.

@ChristophRackwitz, you closed the last question I asked as well. I feel like my experience on SO has been "we understand what you are asking, we don't like the format of your question so we are dismissing you out of hand". Kinda sucks to be honest.
I would say this is an implementation specific question. As it turns out, imposing x>=0 as a constraint allows for higher efficiency in the LP solver, but not all implementations impose this. You can overcome it with a linear shift in your data s.t. a global optimum occurs in x>=0, but knowing how far to shift before hand is not trivial.

which question was that? I don't see it in your recently asked questions. I'm not asking rhetorically. I expect you to link to that "last" question you said "I" closed. -- I didn't do anything on my own. ordinarily, it takes three people to close a question, and so it did with this one. you should not imply what you just implied.

@CooperMaira Unfortunately a lot of people have had the same experience as you. StackOverflow can be pretty unwelcoming. There is a bit of the Milgram experiment showing here. And also a bit of inconsistency about what "closing a question" means and implies. StackOverflow tells its users "Please vote to close a question if you think the question could be improved by edits; this will help the asker; then we'll reopen the question once it's been improved". But most questions don't get reopened once they're closed, and everyone underestimates the effects of closing a question on the asker.

@ChristophRackwitz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78568163/how-to-debayer-an-image-and-add-an-alpha-channel-as-efficiently-as-possible?noredirect=1#comment138528651_78568163. I mean honestly man, I get that the help is free, but it feels like high reputation community members are very dismissive. Also, both times you've voted to close my questions you've said no reproducible code example when neither question would have benefitted from having one. Maybe I'm wrong, but this makes it seem like you're looking to close the question, not looking to improve it.

there is still nothing to this question that makes it a programming question. it's purely a math question, specifically how to formulate LPs. programming itself isn't the issue, it's just "turning the math into practice". x>=0 is a standard constraint, so the question isn't even specific to OpenCV's solver. you'll get the same issue with every other solver. there are standard ways to reformulate the LP to deal with the x >= 0 limitation (see comment by sascha). perhaps some solvers transform the problem under the hood, so the non-negative constraint is loosened without the user noticing?

anyway. I don't know if the site gave me me the option to "vote to move" this to the math stack exchange. if the option was there, I'm sorry I didn't pick it. that only actually moves a question if all three votes also pick the same option, which is frequently not going to be the case.

Note for LP-related problems, https://or.stackexchange.com is often more tolerant/welcoming than stackoverflow.

primarily, thematically more appropriate.

As I have discovered and as discussed in the comments, this solver-imposed constraint is done for efficiency and it is solver-specific. Dantzig, the inventer of linear programming used this in his original simplex algorithm. Not all solvers impose this constraint, but the cv::solveLP() does. If you expected the optimum will not occur in the positive orthant you can apply a linear shift to your input vector (in the case of cv::solveLP() this shift should be done to the b vector) such that the optimum will occur in non-negative space.
However, knowing how far to shift your data is not trivial and insufficiently shifted data will result in cv::solveLP() solving on the intersection of your solution space and the positive orthant. If this region is non-empty then an optimum will exist in this region and the solver will return a reasonable looking but possibly incorrect answer, making it difficult to realize what you've done wrong.
